How to deal with translated names of classical authors in biblatex
How can I deal with translated classical author names when quoting from editions coming from different languages (e.g. Aristotle/Aristote/Aristotele/Aristoteles, etc.) ?
I need to have the author's names appear in the list of references as they are given in the printed book---that is, in the original language. On the other hand, I would also like biblatex to sort them together and properly group them.
I'm using a slightly modified version of the standard author-year style.
I was hoping to find support for an "alternativeAuthor" or something like that, but I could not find anything in the manual nor online.
Suppose I have these two entries:
@Book{AristotleDeGenIt1976,
  author        = {Aristotele},
  editor        = {Maurizio Migliori},
  publisher     = {Loffredo},
  title         = {La generazione e la corruzione},
  date          = {1976},
  address       = {Napoli},
}


@Book{AristotleCategEngl1963,
  author          = {Aristotle},
  editor          = {J. Ackrill},
  publisher       = {Clarendon Press},
  title           = {{\emph{Categories}} and {\emph{De interpretatione}}},
  date            = {1963},
  address         = {Oxford},
  langid    = {english}
}

This is how they appear in the list of references:

Instead, I would like them to be typeset as (since the book's language is English):
Aristotle [Aristotele] (1968).  La Metafisica, etc. 

     ---               (1963).  Categories and De Interpretatione, etc.  

 

Is there a way to achieve this results?

Try with the nameaddon field to provide an alternative translation of the name. You'll need to modify the author's macro.
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifuseauthor}
                and
                not test {\ifnameundef{author}}}
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
            {\bibnamedash}
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
            \printnames{author}%
            \iffieldundef{authortype}
                {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
                {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
            \iffieldundef{authortype}
                {}
                {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
                \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
            \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
    \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
            {}%
            {\setunit{\addspace}%
            \printtext[mkbibbrackets]%
            {\printfield{nameaddon}}}
    \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

I am assuming that your bibliographic style is the authoryear.

Thanks, that works. The only issue is that I do not get the brackets with your \printtext[mkbibbrackets] line. I do get them if take it out and add the "brackets" options to the \printfield command: \printfield[brackets]{nameaddon}.  I also tried to use a different field instead of nameaddon, both a standard one (e.g. "namea") and a newly declared one (e. g. "origauthor" which I defined in a dbx file), but I could not get the driver to recognize either. They always come out as undefined.

Try:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,datamodel=customised]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{customised.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{origauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{origauthor}
\end{filecontents*}
% The brackets: may be that I presumed already defined:
\DeclareFieldFormat{mkbibbrackets}{\bibopenbracket#1\bibclosebracket}
% I see now that, if I don't provide this command, the \printtext[brackets] one doesn't work neither in my new blank sample
I omit the .bib file. In my new blank sample, it works.

Thanks for your edited version, but it's pretty much what I tried. It's certainly my fault---I use a customized version of authoryear and I have probably messed up something. But never mind. Using a custom field would have been cleaner, but the current solution is good enough.
